# Partition Equal Subset Sum Top Down TLE

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am Solving [Partition Equal Subset Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/) of leetcode.

Problem States:

```
Given a non-empty array containing only positive integers, find if the array can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is equal.

Note:

Each of the array element will not exceed 100.
The array size will not exceed 200.
```

I Wrote the Code for the following as

```
class Solution {
public boolean canPartition(int[] nums) {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+nums[i];
    }
    if(sum%2!=0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int target=sum/2;
    return helper(nums,target,nums.length);

}
boolean helper(int nums[],int sum,int n)
{
    if(sum==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(sum<0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(n==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return helper(nums,sum-nums[n-1],n-1)||helper(nums,sum,n-1);
}


 }
```

Notice that I did not included the condition

```
if(sum<nums[n-1])
{
return false;
}
```

in the base case as i have included

```
if(sum<0)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

which is the same thing as it would just add 1 more recursive call and then return false.

This code works for 89 of the test cases but gives TLE error for

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,100]
```

Now if the modify the same code and include

```
if(sum<nums[n-1])
    {
    return false;
    }
```

and remove

```
if(sum<0)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

i.e

```
class Solution {
public boolean canPartition(int[] nums) {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+nums[i];
    }
    if(sum%2!=0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int target=sum/2;
    return helper(nums,target,nums.length);

}
boolean helper(int nums[],int sum,int n)
{
    if(sum==0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(n==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(nums[n-1]>sum)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return helper(nums,sum-nums[n-1],n-1)||helper(nums,sum,n-1);
}
}
```

The code works fine and passes all the Test Cases.

Since both the code are same how is that one extra recursive call giving me TLE?
Is there is something else ?

Comment: It seems to be that `sum < nums[n-1]` is pruning off the recursion tree substantially than the condition `sum < 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The test cases are really weak. First one should get TLE as you did not use dynamic programming but performed a plain backtrack. Second one should get WA. If you used memoization your complexity would be `O( totalSum * arraySize)` but the complexity of your code is O(2 ^ arraySize).

now observe you have two options in every state. Either you pick the element or not. Even if this condition is true `if(nums[n-1]>sum)` , the second option is valid - going forward not picking the item. But your second code ignores both the cases for that condition reducing the calls to the point your solution takes less than 1 millisecond which is faster than most correct solution. As there was no counter test cases for the second solution it passed.

Comment: so dude we dont have a option of going forward if(nums[n-1]>sum) as this sum is the value of sumofarray/2 . 
eg. sum of array us 200 
so my sum=200/2 =>100
now if i find some element say 102 then i will directly return false as there is no point of going forward as array cant be partitioned!

Comment: Run your 2nd code for test case `[4,5,6,5]`. It returns false but the answer is true. If you pick the last 5 your code will not go forward ignoring 6. And if you pick 6 , you will not go forward ignoring 5 . But the array can be partitioned `[4,6]` and `[5,5]`.